# How to use python struct.unpack

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I have a file with the following content

```
(dp1 
S'SomethingString1' 
p2
(dp3
S'SomethingString2' 
p4
I3
sS'SomethingString3' 
p5
I7105
sS'SomethingString4'
p6
I0
```

How do I get data from it using python "struct.unpack"

Answer (score 1):

You have a pickle file, use the [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) instead.

The `struct` module won't help here; that module is used for binary data packed following C struct conventions, and the pickle format you are looking at is textual.